# Media Query override

Tags: css, media

I have the following Media Query that is pre-written in a CMS I am using:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px){
.CalendarViewDayHeader {
background-color: #F00!important;
}
}
```

However I want it to be valid to screen lower resolutions too. The default color (which is blue) does not fit the look of my website. I wrote the following media query  in the supplemental CSS and it does not seem to be working:

```
@media (min-width: 320px){
.CalendarViewDayHeader {
background-color: #F00!important;
}
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot just change the original CSS as it is built in to the CMS. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you link us to the page or show more code? It helps if we can see it and play with it to understand exactly what is happening.

Comment: This should work unless your supplemental file is loaded *before* the original file. In that case, increase specificity (`body .CalendarViewDayHeader`). Are you sure the site isn't cached?

Comment: Do you see your CSS in the document inspector? Is the element inside an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to put the style inline below further down in the cue to make it write over the other styles.